# How to get deferred object value from autobahn RPC call synchronously

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn

I have Autobahn PRC client function defined as followings:

```
 def call_server_get_voltage(self):
 self.call("http://server.com/server#get_voltage").addCallback(self.on_get_voltage)

 def on_get_voltage(self, result_voltage):
 print "on_get_voltage: " + result_voltage
```

Above code calls a RPC server function "get_voltage". It works fine, and voltage is read correctly from RPC server.

But, I want to make a synchronous call. It should look like this following, not getting value in callback function.

```
def call_server_synchronous_get_voltage(self):
(How to combine above callback function, so that it will be synchronous)
return voltage
```

I tried:

a) inlinecallback decorator. But, it still return deferred object.

```
@inlineCallbacks
def call_server_synchronous_get_voltage_inlinecallback(self):
    #'val' is correct value from server
    val = yield self.self.call("http://server.com/server#get_voltage")

    #but how to return it????
    returnValue(val)   #This is deferred object. Not voltage value
```

Could someone help me to understand @inlineCallback? Is this decorator for this purpose?

b) I tried Crochet  @wait_for decorator. It should make callback disappear from caller.

```
@wait_for(timeout=10)
def call_server_synchronous_get_voltage_crochet(self):

    val = self.self.call("http://server.com/server#get_voltage")
    val.addCallback(lambda result: result)  

    return val
```

This function does return correct value. But it works only once. I am calling `call_server_synchronous_get_voltage_crochet()` from a Django server to display a web page. When reload web page 2nd time, the Autobahn RPC connection to server is dropped with is error:

`Lost client connection: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>: Connection was closed cleanly.
]`

How to make call to Autobahn RPC and get result back synchronously?

Comment: Your `wait_for` code uses `inlineCallbacks` instead...

Comment: I need to make correction to my original question.

b) I tried Crochet @wait_for decorator. It should make callback disappear from caller.
@wait_for(timeout=5)
def call_server_synchronous_get_voltage_crochet(self):

    val = yield self.self.call("http://server.com/server#get_voltage")
    val.addCallback(lambda result: result)  

    return val

Comment: Click the "edit" button at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

To use Crochet, you probably shouldn't be yielding anything.

```
@wait_for(timeout=10)
def call_server_synchronous_get_voltage_crochet(self):
    val = self.self.call("http://server.com/server#get_voltage")
    val.addCallback(lambda result: result)  
    return val
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My original post had an error. yield should not be used. My posted result is the result without using yield. Sorry about it. So, it does work for 1st time. But, when it's called 2nd time, the rpc connection is dropped, and call never happen for 2nd call and calls after that. Not sure if 1) I used Crocket incorrectly; 2) my program has other issues. Based on your post, I am using Crochet correctly. Is there other way to do it without Crochet?

Comment: Update: wait_for decorator does work reliably. The issue of rpc connection drop proved to be other issue I have to deal with.

Comment: I can't help with that unless you provide more information.